# Consider time range between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making slots for booking on my calendar. I'm doing the structure of the page, so for now it has no css.

**EDIT: 1st problem--> SOLVED using code posted in 2nd problem**

**2nd problem:** if i use:

```
$array8 = array($newinizio >= $ore8 && $newinizio <= $ore830 || $newfine >= $ore8 && $newfine <= $ore830);
    if (count(array_filter($array8)) == 1)
    {    $bg8 = 'yellow';}
    if (count(array_filter($array8)) >= 2)
    {    $bg8 = 'red';}
```

so i set background color yellow if timestart($newinizio) or timeend ($newfine) are between value1 ($ore8) and value2 ($ore830), it consider only timestart and timeend , so make my button yellow only if start or end are in this range. How can i consider also the duration? I mean

Event 1 Start 8:00 End 9:10 -----> set background-color yellow also for the button that has timerange 8:30-9:00

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by your first question: ">= 1"? Looks like are dealing with boolean logic (true/false), so expect a true/false, not a number. Also: Use more ( and ) to make sure things evaluate in the order you want them to.

Comment: @ErwinMoller  I mean that i want that:
IF events in range are 0 ---> don't set color;
IF event in range is 1 ---> set color yellow;
IF events in range are 2 ore more ---> set color red;
How can i do it?

Comment: very confusing that you mention `$timestart` and `$timeend` and `$value1` and `$value2` but those don't appear in your code.  do events have  just a single time, or a start and an end and you are looking for events that overlap a time range?

Comment: i mention $timestart and $timeend cause my values are in italian, i just edited my question with real variables